# Can I generate a FirefoxOS App from game written using starling framework?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox-os, starling-framework

A friend of mine has developed an excellent game using the starling framework. He is now wondering if he could port the game to FirefoxOS before he launches. The game is written in actionscript 3 and the starling framework project can build mobile packages for android and ios. It also can generate the flash file for the web (using flash player). Are there any paths for porting the game to FirefoxOS?

Someone suggested using [shumway](https://github.com/mozilla/shumway). If you know about this way, or any other path, please give a bief account of advantages/disadvantages. I am specially concerned about the performance, since the game in question has very high quality graphics. I think it needs to run in a GPU accelerated environment.

Answer (score 1):

EaselJS uses a similar syntax to ActionScript; it has a Display List, Stage, Graphics and even Filters, this will make working with the canvas easier for us Flash developers.

I suggest you to port that game to EaselJS and TweenJS (both from CreateJS), I have used it to develop games for Firefox OS and worked quite well.

An advantage is that CreateJS now uses a WebGL renderer, but it also has a fall back to Context2D rendering if WebGL is not available. That would make your device more widely supported.

You will find all its features very explained in the following post from Mozilla Hacks. It has also some cool benchmarks to try it.

[WebGL and CreateJS for FirefoxOS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/01/webgl-createjs-for-firefox-os/)

Comment: thanks @Cod1ngFree, I will pass on this information to my friend